# Propagation of Poisson Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, error-propagation

I have a set of measurement with 95% Poisson confidence intervals, and I would like to subtract and multiply them and propagate the error. For example, I measured the copy number of a piece of DNA in a biological sample as 0.0268, 95% CI = 0.308-0.227.  I know there are systematic biases in my measurement, ie issues with sensitivity and specificity, which I independently determined.  For example, to measure sensitivity I spiked in a known concentration of copies of DNA, 467 copies per ul, and I measured 251 copies per ul, 95% CI 255-248, so arround 54%.  To measure specificity I used a known negative DNA sample, so expected 0 copy number but measured 0.00162, 95% CI 0.0023-0.000936.
I would like to multiply the measured copy number by the specificity, which would give a value of ~.496, then subtract the specificity, which would yield a final copy number estimate of ~.494. How can I propagate the errors in this case?

Comment: You need a model for how your actual values are leading to your measured values. I could make a guess, but you'd be better placed to suggest what's going on to produce the two outcomes you discuss there.

Comment: By model, do you mean what is going on molecularly to produce this result?  If so, then I think I know exactly what is going on.  My assay is detecting both my target and a similar piece of DNA, that is why I see signal in the absence of target.  For this reason I had to tweak the assay so that it detects this non-target molecular at as low efficiency as possible, which had the side effect of reducing the efficiency of true target detection, ergo the 54% efficiency. Does that explain things?

Comment: That's the kind of background knowledge from which one might build a model (in the statistics/probability sense), which would be a mathematical description of the way that those things impact what you observe.

Comment: Why do I need a model for this seemingly basic question?  I can think of analogous situtations where models are not needed, for example when examining the gene expression level of a gene of interest (gene A) and loading control (gene B), one can take a ratio of gene A to gene B, and propagate the SD from both measurements to get an SD of the ratio.  How is this different?

Comment: Knowing to take a *ratio* would presumably rely on domain knowledge (a model, in the intended sense) that someone without domain knowledge won't have. "Reduce" isn't at all specific. "In a ratio" is much more specific. You just used a model, even if you don't recognize it.

Comment: So it seems like you are saying I already have a model.  Maybe my initial question was not stated clearly enough, so I will break it up and restate.  (1) How can I propagate the error when subtracting mean values with 95% confidence intervals. (2) How can I propagate the error when dividing mean values with 95% confidence intervals?

Comment: That's much clearer to my poor brain, at least.

Comment: For anyone else looking for this answer, stumbling upon this fascinating but so far unproductive exchange, I have found elsewhere that the 95% CI = 1.96 x SD, and one can use the formulas here (http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html) to propagate the error.

Comment: I have been composing an answer, but if your problem is already solved, you should compose one instead.